# Cannot find symbol for the method "setString(int,String)" in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to build a simple username-password login application in Netbeans. I have stored the username and password in PhpMyAdmin database. When I use `PreparedStatement` to `setString` in the textfield, it shows the error saying that: `Cannot find symbol for the method setString(int, String)`.

**Working Code:**

```
  //Importing stuffs

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

private void enterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { //login button                                     

       String sql = "select * from UserInfo where Username=? and Password=?";
       try{
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/phpmyadmin/LoginInfo", "root","");
           pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
           pst = setString(1, username.getText());//error here
           pst = setString(2, password.getText());//error here
           rs= pst.executeQuery();
           if(rs.next()){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "good");
           }else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "bad");  
           }
       }catch(Exception ex){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Voting to close as a trivial/typographic error

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a frontend tool for MySQL, it has nothing to do with connecting to MySQL from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use :

```
pst = setString(1, username.getText());//error here
pst = setString(2, password.getText());//error here
```

use this instead :

```
pst.setString(1, username.getText());
pst.setString(2, password.getText());
```

---

read this tutorial about [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)